# "Incorrect password" error when report opened first time

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

This error appears when I preview the report for first time in Crystal Reports or my Java App. I am passing the correct password, but I get the password mismatch error. After the error, the report opens. How can I resolve this?

> Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
>   Login failed for user '@@@@@@'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.

Comment: If you have sub-reports or dynamic LOV (list of value) as associated with a parameter, they could be pointing to a different data source.

Comment: I do have both sub-reports and dynamic LOV. They are pointing to the same data source.

Comment: Can you create a XML of your RPT file and post it online for us to see? The tool is here: https://github.com/ajryan/RptToXml - The relevant portion of the XML is `<Database>` or `<Table>` section

Comment: Cannot post XML file. Anything else

Comment: Run rpttoxml and see if you have additional data source. You need to check data source in sub report. Also for LOV, you need at least read access to Crystal Server Business View Manager (?). Can be problem if you upgraded crystal server recently.